# They'll deliver it in two hours. (meaning, we'll have this in two hours)

Tags: perfect-constructions, future-time, future-constructions, future-perfect

Browsing through an online store, a girl points at a certain item and says, *"Wow, let's order this! They(or A courier) **'ll deliver** it in two hours (meaning, two hours from now, if we do order it now)!"*.

Can she say "will deliver it"?

I mean, the courier will, in fact, **finish** delivering it in two hours, having started delivering, let's say, at least half an hour before (depends on how long it takes to get here).

I'm trying to figure out how the simple form of the verb "deliver" works in English, whether it says about the whole action of delivering **or** only the final moment. The latter makes more sense to me, but if the former is the case, will the perfect form *"will have delivered it in two hours"* fix this?

- (simple active) Wow, let's order this! They(or A courier)'ll **deliver** it in two hours!
- (simple passive) Wow, let's order this! It'll **be delivered** in two hours!
- (perfect active) Wow, let's order this! They(or A courier)'ll **have delivered** it in two hours!
- (perfect passive) Wow, let's order this! It'll **have been delivered** it in two hours!

Comment: If you're suggesting that a company that says it will deliver an item in one day merely means they will begin the process in one day, even if it takes five days to reach the customer, no.  When a company promises delivery, they mean that they will see to it that you receive the item in the stated time. And that's true even when the delivery truck is on a delivery and the driver *is delivering* the package while the driver is en route. We'd use the perfect, **have delivered**, to indicate that the delivery has been completed.

Comment: Yes, *will deliver* is a promise of results. If you promise to deliver in 2 hours, I don't care about your travels or your process, I expect it in 2.

Comment: The best choice (all of them are fine grammatically, by the way) would be based on a broader context.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice I know it's a different verb, but this is still an English verb and all tense rules apply to it as well. So, does this logic also work with the verb "marinade"? For example, "I put the turkey into marinade two hours ago and it **will marinade** in ten hours (the whole process takes 12 hours), then you can cook it".

Comment: There the transitive verb  **marinade** (var. of **marinate**) is being used in a perfective sense (i.e. be finished marinating) but without the past participle in either a passive construction (have been fully marinaded) or a deverbal adjective (be marinated). It's analogous to "In three minutes the tea will steep". That usage strikes my ear as marginal. I would say "In three minutes the tea will have steeped"  or "be finished steeping"  or "The turkey will be done marinating in ten hours."  But in sub-domains (e.g. cookery) words can develop new uses and meanings as a kind of jargon.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice it's so over complicated in English. So frustrating :(

Comment: If the verb is being used intransitively, you need some kind of periphrastic construction:  **will be done marinating, will be finished steeping**.  **will** plus the bare form of the verb (*will marinate*) doesn't express perfective aspect. But **will** plus an adjective formed from the past participle of a transitive verb (if one exists) in combination with an adverb can be used to express that notion: "**will be fully  (or sufficiently) marinated** in ten hours".

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice That's VERY helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice one question, you said "if the verb is being used intransitively", but what if I'm using it transitively? Like here, "I'll marinate the turkey in 20 minutes", does it mean that I'll finish marinating it in 20 minutes? (by "I'll marinate it", I mean I'll apply necessary spices in order to then put it in the fridge to let it marinate -itself- for about 12 hours until it has fully marinated -itself-)

Comment: No, the simple present doesn't imply perfected state at all. The past participle does, either in tensed form "I have marinated the turkey" (active) or "the turkey has been marinated" (passive) or in an adjective formed from the past participle: "The turkey is marinated"

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Thanks again! Very helpful! So how then should I say that? "I'll marinate the turkey in 20 minutes" doesn't work as I want it to, so what are your options? As for me, I would think of "I'll be done marinating ... in 20 minutes" or "I'll finish marinating ... in 20 minutes"." or "I'll have marinated ... in 20 minutes".

Comment: I am not sure what idea you are trying to express.  Are you trying to speak of your own actions in the turkey preparation process, or of the turkey's state?  "I will start the turkey marinating" or "I'll put the turkey in to marinate" are possibilities for the former.    You yourself cannot complete the marination, as it is a process, like steeping, which you can only initiate and terminate.  English is often quite logical :-)

Comment: But you can say "I will have marinated the turkey by then" in reference to a stage in the turkey prep process. But it wouldn't be clear whether you meant you had started it or ended it.  This might be clearer: " I will have finished marinating the turkey by then."  Clearest would be to speak of the turkey's state: "The turkey will have finished marinating by then." or "The turkey will be done marinating by then".

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice To answer your question of what I meant: I understand the action of marinating smth as presented in two parts: The first part when **you** actually marinate, for example, a turkey by applying different ingredients on it (transitive meaning) and the second part when you let the turkey marinate -itself- (intransitive meaning) in the fridge until it is fully marinated. Just to make things clear — in Russian there are two (among others) verb forms for these purposes. One that shows that you're working on something and another that shows that this something is working on itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct depending on the situation.

Deliver generally refers to the final moment when referring to the timing of parcel deliveries. However, there are other usages such as the famous "deliver us from evil" phrase in the lord's prayer and the sentence "you delivered a great speech yesterday" where the word refers to a whole action.

Welcome to English!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Yeah, "Welcome to English!" is a very suitable thing to say here ahhahahah