# In two hours, he <will deliver><will have delivered> it

Tags: verbs, future-constructions, future-perfect, future

Please, help me understand how these verbs work in English. Should I use the simple or the perfect aspect to talk about the final moment of the actions (when the intended effect comes in power)?

marinate

- I put the turkey into marinade two hours ago and it **will marinate** in ten hours (the whole process takes 12 hours), then you can cook it.
- I put the turkey into marinade two hours ago and it **will have marinated** in ten hours (the whole process takes 12 hours), then you can cook it.

steep/brew

- I put a teabag in the mug and poured in boiling water a minute ago. The tea **will steep/brew** in two minutes (the whole process takes 3 minutes), then you can drink it.
- I put a teabag in the mug and poured in boiling water a minute ago. The tea **will have steeped/brewed** in two minutes (the whole process takes 3 minutes), then you can drink it.

deliver

- The courier started delivering the order an hour ago (He's still delivering it). He'**ll deliver** it in two hours.
- The courier started delivering the order an hour ago (He's still delivering it). He'**ll have delivered** it in two hours.

[I've asked about this one already](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345315/theyll-deliver-it-in-two-hours-meaning-well-have-this-in-two-hours?noredirect=1#comment668720_345315)

Comment: It will marinade is wrong. The verb is: to marina**te**.  We marinate X for [number of hours].

Comment: The future perfect is used to suggest an action will be finished/completed before a specific time in the future while the simple future does not. It only refers to a future time when an action/event will happen.

Comment: @Lambie I've fixed it now, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand that, but the point is that English speaking people's understanding of "It will happen" can be very different from my understanding. I would treat each of these actions in the simple aspect as finished, but I'm not sure about that now after receiving some replies (from the link I've provided at the bottom) about the verbs "deliver" and "marinate".

Comment: The marinate and steep examples are awkward, because first ***in X timelength*** refers to how long marinating or steeping *should take*, then it refers to how long it's been since the last point in time mentioned. But the courier one is straightforward: *He'll deliver it in two hours* means he will deliver ***AT that specific time***. On the other hand, *He'll have delivered it in two hours* means he will deliver ***BEFORE that specific time*** (so ***by*** that time, the delivery will already have taken place).

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov -Yes we will still understand these from context, because you have already included a time in the sentence with the simple future. However, the first one about marinating is a little odd, because marinating is a process that takes time.  IMHO it would be better to say "will marinate **for** ten hours", also similar for brewing:  "will brew **for** 3 minutes.". This isn't a major mistake however.  Deliver is a little different - When we "deliver" something, it's generally understood as a one-time/single event. It's absolutely fine to say "He will deliver it **in** two hours".

Comment: What's the point of fixing one thing if the other is wrong? It will have [past participle of action verb] is not about the final minutes. It's about a timeline where will have past participle is asking for you to understand that in the future some action will be finished.